# String.IsNullOrEmpty or string.IsNullOrEmpty

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

I have been looking through code for the last 3 days, and the original developer is defining Strings using the *String* class rather than the *string* class.  So, when they've used the *IsNullOrEmpty* method, it's defined *String.IsNullOrEmpty*.

What I'd like to know is how is the compiler dealing with *String.IsNullOrEmpty* compared to *string.IsNullOrEmpty*?

Is there any advantages using *String.IsNullOrEmpty* over *string.IsNullOrEmpty*?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They are both the same.

string is a keyword alias in c# for System.String.

Only difference is that when using String, you need to use either `System.String.IsNullOrEmpty` or `using System;` at the begining of your code file.

Comment: Create yourself a static class called StringUtilities and define an extension method called IsNullOrEmpty:

public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string @this) { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(@this); }.

This allows you to call it as a method of the variable you are checking, e.g. fred.IsNullOrEmpty().

Answer (score 6):

String stands for **System.String** and it is a .NET Framework type. **string is an alias** in the C# language for System.String. Both of them are compiled to **System.String in IL** (Intermediate Language), so there is no difference. Choose what you like and use that. If you code in C#, I'd prefer string as it's a C# type alias and well-know by C# programmers.

I can say the same about **(int, System.Int32)** etc..

Answer (score 4):

They are the same.

Personally, I prefer to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty`. The alternative just doesn't look right. The same goes for choosing `Int32.Parse(...)` over `int.Parse(...)`. And, of course, no matter what approach you choose, be consistent.

Comment: Yeah. string.IsNullOrEmpty(...) looks like we're trying to do a method call on a keyword (depending on your syntax highlighting settings of course). But we're really splitting hairs here. I keep to String.IsNullOrEmpty, but I don't fix it if I see string.IsNullOrEmpty in my colleagues' code.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefered to use CTS types, if I used static methods like `IsNullOrEmpty` or `Parse`. But after I read the article *Coding Standards for .NET* by Lance Hunt (http://se.inf.ethz.ch/old/teaching/ss2007/251-0290-00/project/CSharpCodingStandards.pdf) specially the notice *Use built-in C# native data types vs .NET CTS types*, I have revised my opinion. Now I use ever  corresponding types for declatations and for calling of functions, and I use the aliasses if possible.
Consider, maybe are `int` and `Int32` not the same in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Since VS2019 suggests to simplify using the struct instead of the class, I would follow its recommendations, even though you must be consistent in your overall solution.
[image: Simplification suggestion]